# centos dropbox newest version not starting

Tags: centos, upgrade, dropbox

I have some issues getting dropbox to run on Centos 6.3. These issues started after I recently got a security warning to upgrade Dropbox. Before this, the older version (not sure which one exactly) has been running fine for ~2+ years.

The install I did was:

Download:
https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/fedora/nautilus-dropbox-1.6.2-1.fedora.x86_64.rpm

Install:
`yum localinstall nautilus-dropbox-1.6.2-1.fedora.x86_64.rpm`

After this:
`dropbox start -i`

It downloads successfully, but then when I do:

`dropbox start`

I get the message:

> Dropbox isn't running!
>
> Dropbox is already running!

And nothing else happens.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Try renaming `~/.dropbox` or moving it somewhere else from home dir.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried this, and the ~/.dropbox gets re-created, but the problem remains the same...

Comment: Can you run `ps aux | grep dropbox` ? May be it's already running? Well since it's creating new folder, it means it is running, can you try to upload some files?

Comment: Yes, looks like it is running indeed. But it is not linked to my account atm. And since it I cannot access the GUI of dropbox, I cannot link it I guess...

Comment: Actually you can use it in gui-less mode, check [link](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/install-dropbox-in-an-entirely-text-based-linux-environment)

Comment: Same issue here(Centos 6.6) after have installed `nautilus-dropbox` (x86_64) 2.10.0-1.fc10 from: `http://linux.dropbox.com/fedora/20/`. Before the last update, it was working without problems!

Answer (score 1):

I got this temporary solution from dropbox

```
killall dropbox
rm ~/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86*/libxml2.so.2
~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd &
```